# List sub-folders and their files using Command-line in different Drives

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I have some folders in different drives on my Windows computer:

```
E:\folder1
F:\folder2\folder3
G:\folder4
H:\folder5
H:\folder6\folder7\folder8
...
```

As you see above, the folders do not have the same parent. (I am keeping above folder nmaes in a text file.)  I want to list sub-folders and files of the above folders.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("textfile.txt") do (
   dir /b /s "%%a" >>"%userprofile%\desktop\results.txt"
)
pause
```